# how is that possible if I want add one specific plot around my city? somthings like close it

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I use this vid tutorial to make a random road city (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baiIAJ_THIc) , now I want to add one specific plot around my city. somethings like close it.

[image]

(buildings are hidden)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think I would do something like that...

It's done by something like this, thank you
[image]